# Protecting my microservice with the express api gateway

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express apigateway for a node.js microservice api application

https://www.express-gateway.io/

I am looking for a situation where the express apigateway will be the only unit that will make my microservices available

MicroserviceAuth

MicroserviceProjects

I don't want a situation where a user will know my url and call MicroserviceProjects directly. I want it to go through the express apigateway.
How can I set this up?

Comment: Are your services running in a cloud environment?

Comment: No. I have not deployed yet. They are running locally.

Comment: I was asking because usually the cloud environment will let you define who can make requests to your service. For example in AWS you can define a Security Group and restrict IPs, certain traffic, ports, etc etc. So if you deployed the service access restriction, could be done in minutes!